# How to protect the SQLite database in the Android studio app before publishing?

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I've been working on an Android App using a sensitive data stored in an external SQLite database in the Assets directory.
I edit it externally and put it back to the project.
I don't want to leave it in the project directory at publishing because of reskinning.
What am I supposed to do?

Some of my friends have advised me to use back-end and a login system to send the database from the server to the application users only after verifying their identity, but this will be very expensive for me in the initial period of publishing the application?
Is there anything alternative that protects the database well (such as encrypting it in Android Studio) until I buy hosting for the server?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

> encrypting it in Android Studio

You may be interested in  https://github.com/sqlcipher/android-database-sqlcipher (as a possible solution)

A search on SQLCipher would show many links to examples of use.

Comment: But what are the benefits of SQLCipher if I have to include the database password to my Android application, I think it's very easy for the attacker who trying to reskin my app to get the password from Kotlin files, isn't it?
Is there a proper way to protect my password, or are there any other solutions?

Comment: @AhmedEL_Telbani to protect anything then you must somehow control access when the App is installed i.e. you will need something that is not available via the App install but via a protected means e.g. the SQLCipher key if encrypting the database provided somehow.